# Default value for a parameter in bigquery procedure

Tags: google-bigquery

In SQL Server, we can specify a default value for a parameter. For eg:

This procedure pattern matches the parameters passed or, if not supplied, uses the preset default (last names that start with the letter D).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployees2
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50) = N'D%',
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = N'%'
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Department
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment
    WHERE FirstName LIKE @FirstName AND LastName LIKE @LastName;
```

I couldn't find anything related to default value for stored procedure's parameters. Is there no concept of default value for a parameter in Bigquery?

Comment: Can't you pass in `NULL` and use `COALESCE(@LASTNAME, N'D%')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `NULL` value and then use `COALESCE(Param, 'default_value')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).